# AC not working in 2013 Honda CRV

Tags: honda, ac, crv, compressor

The air-conditioning in my 2013 Honda CRV went out about a year ago. It started going out intermittently, and then it died altogether. I’ve bought the compressor, the condenser, and the expansion valve to replace.

However, when I hook the gauges to the low and high pressure ports, they show zero pressure in lines. If I crank the car up turn the AC on, the clutch doesn’t spin or engage. With the car turned off, I can’t spin the clutch by hand either.

If I try to add refrigerant, the pressure gauge on the bottle never gets off zero. I added the dye to try to find a leak, but I don’t see one. What is going on?

Before I spend all the time and money replacing everything, I’d like to understand what is actually broken.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you tried to draw a vacuum on the system yet?

Comment: Why are you adding refrigerant to a dead locked up compressor?, more than likely all the refrigerant leaked out.

Comment: Yep. You’re right. I figured it out. The compressor flew apart. I swapped it it and it went back to running.